# Раскрывающиеся блоки с скрытым содержанием

Tags: html, css, css3, вёрстка, вкладки

Нужно сверстать блок (см. картинку 1) который при клике разворачивался и показывал другой блок с другим текстом (см. картинку 2). Как это можно сверстать?

[image: Картинка 1]

[image: Картинка 2]

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_collapsible.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Могу предположить, что Вам с JavaScript разобраться будет пока что слишком сложно. Поэтому вот решение на чистом CSS:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 10px;
}

.accordion {
  transform: translateZ(0);
  background: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
  border-left: 1px solid lightgray;
  border-right: 1px solid lightgray;
}

.accordion>.accordion-toggle {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}

.accordion>label {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  border-top: 1px solid lightgray;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
  background: #ecebec;
  color: #555;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.accordion>label:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  right: 20px;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border-left: 2px solid #555;
  border-top: 2px solid #555;
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
  transition: 0.4s transform;
}

.accordion>section {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 0;
  transition: all .4s;
}

.accordion>.accordion-toggle:checked~label:after {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: 16px;
}

.accordion>.accordion-toggle:checked~section {
  height: 50px;
}

.accordion>section p {
  margin: 15px 0;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="accordion">
  <input id="toggle1" type="radio" class="accordion-toggle" name="toggle" />
  <label for="toggle1">Вкладка 1</label>
  <section>
    <p>Текст 1</p>
  </section>
</div>
<div class="accordion">
  <input id="toggle2" type="radio" class="accordion-toggle" name="toggle" />
  <label for="toggle2">Вкладка 2</label>
  <section>
    <p>Текст 2</p>
  </section>
</div>
<div class="accordion">
  <input id="toggle3" type="radio" class="accordion-toggle" name="toggle" />
  <label for="toggle3">Вкладка 3</label>
  <section>
    <p>Текст 3</p>
  </section>
</div>
<div class="accordion">
  <input id="toggle4" type="radio" class="accordion-toggle" name="toggle" />
  <label for="toggle4">Вкладка 4</label>
  <section>
    <p>Текст 4</p>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let div = document.querySelector('div');
let p = document.querySelector('p');
div.addEventListener('click', () => {
  p.style.display = 'block';
  let span = document.querySelector('span').style.cssText = `
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  right: 30px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  top: 15px;
  `;
})
```

```css
div{
  color: red;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ECEBEC;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: relative;
}
span{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  right: 30px;
  transform: rotate(223deg);
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  top: 0;
}
div > p{
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  text
  <span></span>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</p>
</div>
```